# how to notify the server every 5 minutes on user's location?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I write an android app.

I want to send the server the user's location every 5 minutes even if he hasn't moved.

how would you suggest me to do it?

Using a Timer and just sending the location every 5 min

or using locationListener with minDistance = 0 m and minTime = 5 min?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a `AlarmManager` that would wake up every 5 minutes and use `LocationListener`to get the current location to send to server. After sending location updates, just unregister(remove updates) the locationListener. In this way, you will be improving the battery performance. Imagine the case where your `locationListener` keeps running in the background.

Comment: what's the difference between Timer and AlarmManager?

Comment: They are kinda same thing, except that you write timer inside some activity. AlarmManager will get called through BroadCastReceiver.

Comment: i want to optimize this: how can I recognize the device isn't used for more than 30 minutes and then not to send an update to the server. And restart the Alarm manager again after user first touch.

Comment: `Imagine the case where your locationListener keeps running in the background.` doesn't java optimize it and keep the listener asleep for minTime parameter anyway?